# SQL Service Broker: "orphaned" messages in sys.sysxmitqueue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, service-broker

I have a database running under SQL 2016 that is using service broker to handle some business logic.  I did not design the system, I'm still not 100% sure how it works, but I definitely know that it's in a really bad state at the moment.

Someone before me had created a SQL agent job to clean up old broker conversations, I'm assuming because they're not closing them out correctly.  I noticed that this job was taking longer and longer to run each day (it selects TOP (X) rows, then does END CONVERSATION WITH CLEANUP if it's older than a couple of days and in DO or DI status).  I did some digging and looked at the service broker system tables:

sys.sysdercv:  ~268,000,000 rows, ~144GB in size

sys.sysdesend:  ~268,000,000 rows, ~20GB in size

sys.sysxmitqueue:  130 rows, size insignificant

Judging by the Enqueued Messages/sec performance counter, it looks like we create ~90 messages per second.

In the sys.sysxmitqueue table, I can see that the 130 rows that are "stuck" in there have an enqtime sometime on 7/1/2016 (this particular database was actually moved from another instance via backup/restore a few months ago, I was not part of that process, so I don't know if they missed any broker related steps).  How can I clear these out?  I was hoping that the dlgid value was a conversation handle, and I'd be able to end the conversations related to these messages.  There are no conversations for those values though.

And while I'm at it, is there any better way to clean out the old conversations than looping through them?  I've seen some people say that this is the way to go:

ALTER DATABASE  SET NEW_BROKER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;

However, I'm not sure if that's the best way to do it, or how long it will take given the size of our system tables, or if it will lose any messages in progress (I'm assuming it will).

Any advice you could provide would be greatly appreciated.  I've never had to deal with service broker before, and it has definitely been a frustrating experience so far.

Comment: NEW_BROKER will remove all conversations so you'll lose messages in transit. That might be the best option being in such a bad state.  Is this all local SB? The need to routinely end conversations with cleanup looks at best to be a band-aid (or should I say tourniquet) for bad design or buggy code.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's all local or not, I'm in the middle of trying to trace out how they designed this mess in the first place.  There are 20 queues, 10 of them have activation procs.  Each proc seems to shuttle messages to other queues depending on some logic, and I've yet to track down which queue is at the top of the chain, or what sticks messages into these queues in the first place.

And I agree, they definitely aren't ending conversations correctly.  I'm sure someone came up with that job as an afterthought.  I can't even get a row count out of sys.transmission_queue at this point.

Comment: Just to follow up on this, I think I have resolved the issue.  Turns out they had created a loop with the queues for certain messages, fixing that problem dropped enqueued messages/sec from 90/second to 0.5/second.  Fixing that sped up my cleanup proc, so it's clearing out conversations at a much faster rate.  I'm expecting to have it all cleared up in about three weeks (still a long time, but safer than creating a new broker for the database and dealing with potential issues).

Comment: Thanks for adding that, @JeffLehn. The `WITH CLEANUP` option should not be used routinely. I think that should be investigated as it could be masking another problem.